# How to get the particular div values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have one row, in that one row I have three div, my requirement is suppose if I am click the free plan button means I want to take only the that particular div values like Plan Name: Free Plan and Bonus Contact details up to : 00, I tried but I am not able to take the exact values if anyone know means please update my answer.Please see below I have posted my code what I tried, I spent too much to this but still I am not getting my answer.

```
<section id="pricing-table">
  <div class="row pricelistNew">
    <div class="pricing"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>    
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Easy Plan</a>
          </div>

          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 25</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 2</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Cool Plan</a>
          </div>

          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 48</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 4</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : Yes</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>   
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Free Plan</a>
          </div>

          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 5</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 00</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

My jQuery code

```
$(function() {
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricelistNew");
    name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

Here I am getting all title names like

> Easy Plan Cool Plan Free Plan

Comment: why don't you loop through them? something like                                        
  $list.find(".myTitle li")..each(function() {
  let eachValue = this.val();
});

Comment: you can use `$(this).prev().prev().text()` i can suggest this since i cant see `pricelistNew`

Comment: You're going up too high:  `.closest(".pricelistNew")` should be `.closest(".pricing-header")` (or `.pricing-table`)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script with this..

```
$(function() {
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricing-table");
      name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();

    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

Comment: Tip: add a comment saying what's changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var list = $(this).closest(".pricing-header");
    var name = list.find(".myTitle").text();
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="pricing-table">
  <div class="row pricelistNew">
    <div class="pricing">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000
              <br><span>Including All Tax</span>
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Easy Plan</a>
          </div>
          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 25</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 2</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000
              <br><span>Including All Tax</span>
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Cool Plan</a>
          </div>
          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 48</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 4</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : Yes</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pricing-table">
          <div class="pricing-header">
            <p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>
            <p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0
              <br><span>Including All Tax</span>
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Free Plan</a>
          </div>
          <div class="pricing-list">
            <ul>
              <li>Contacts details up to : 5</li>
              <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 00</li>
              <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
              <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ,how to take the Contacts details up to values like suppose i am clicking Free Plan button means i want to the Contacts details up to values is 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have edited the your jquery function UI issues due to css

```js
$(function() {
  $(".payNow").on("click", function(e) {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".pricing-table");
      name = $list.find(".myTitle").text();
      name += $($list.find("li")[1]).text();

    console.log(name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="pricing-table">
<div class="row pricelistNew">
<div class="pricing">

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="pricing-table">
<div class="pricing-header">
<p class="pricing-title myTitle">Easy Plan </p>

<p class="pricing-rate">₹ 1000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
<a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Easy Plan</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-list">
<ul>
    <li>Contacts details up to : 25</li>
     <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 2</li>
     <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
     <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="pricing-table">
<div class="pricing-header">
<p class="pricing-title myTitle">Cool Plan </p>

<p class="pricing-rate">₹ 2000 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
<a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Cool Plan</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-list">
<ul>
    <li>Contacts details up to : 48</li>
     <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 4</li>
     <li>Area Master Assistance : Yes</li>
     <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="pricing-table">
<div class="pricing-header">
<p class="pricing-title myTitle">Free Plan </p>

<p class="pricing-rate">₹ 0 <br><span>Including All Tax</span></p>
<a class="btn btn-custom payNow">Free Plan</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-list">
<ul>
    <li>Contacts details up to : 5</li>
     <li>Bonus Contact details up to : 00</li>
     <li>Area Master Assistance : No</li>
     <li>Contact details through sms : Yes</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```